# Devise, blank password_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, xmlhttprequest

Need to do ajax side-registration with devise. Created RegistrationsController:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create 
    if request.xhr?
      build_resource(sign_up_params)

      if resource.save
        ...
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

Noticed, that model does not validate confirmation of password, if I don't pass that field in XHR, or the field is empty, and Angular does not gather it before doing $http.post

Hacked it for a while in Angular, hardcoding initial `$scope.reg = {'password_confirmation': ''}` but wonder how do I fix this a normal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that your model's password confirmation is not validated once you've properly set up Devise. You'll know for sure if validation isn't being run if registration actually creates a new user. If it doesn't create a new user, then validation works fine.

The problem seems to lie in your `create` action. It looks like your `if resource.save` doesn't have an `else` block which is what is called when `resource.save` fails due to validation errors. Your `create` action should look like:

```
  def create
    # seems unnecessary to check if request is xhr
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if resource.save
      render json: resource
    else
      render :json => { :errors => @model.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422
    end
  end
```

Then just have code in Angular that handles errors by notifying the user.

Comment: I wouldnt ask before checking regular devise registration - it works just fine, I think because of password_confirmation field that constantly persist in form, no matter is it filled, or not. The problem is that validation on confirm field doesnt work, if passed data does not contain password_confirm key. If i pass that key, validation works fine. By the way, my create function repeats parent, just beside answers